# How ACF Advanced Custom Field works with Woocommerce Single Product

Tags: plugins, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Field ACF Wordpress plugin and i created many custom fields, here is the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

My question is how can i show these custom fields in woocommerce single product page so my customer can put data while ordering.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ACF is the plugin that you need for this kind of goal. ACF provides an ability to add custom fields in the admin panel and shows the data supplied in the frontend.

What you need is a plugin that will allow you to add custom fields for users to fill up in the frontend. It could be done with this plugin from Booster.io https://booster.io/features/woocommerce-product-input-fields/

But of course there might be more similar ones if it cannot satisfy your need

Comment: thanks for recomendataion, is booster.io save data in order meta ? like can i extra submitted information by using this snippet ?

`echo '<p><strong>'.__('Product').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'my_custom_field', true ) . '</p>';`

Comment: I'm quite confused by what you are trying to do. You said, you want a field where your users can fill up while ordering. What you are showing now in this comment is "get_post_meta" which is to retrieve and show.

Comment: Sir I want to do both tasks, I want to get data from customer on product single page and then display in order details page. Here are the screenshots
1. function.php : http://i.imgur.com/3uJEveo.png
2. order edit page : http://i.imgur.com/0HqX5tl.png

Comment: currently i am using ACF but i didnot know how can i show my input fields in single product page so my customers can put data. I just need to know how to show my custom fields inputs in single product page. Regards.

Comment: In that case you can use ACF to show the admin populated fields. As for the fields that you want users to supply during the checkout process, you can add custom fields using the booster plugin. They can word hand-in-hand. Or, you can manually do that : https://tommcfarlin.com/woocommerce-input/